# Powering a grid of peltier tiles using a power supply

Tags: power, resistance, peltier

I'm trying to supply power to an 8x8 grid of peltier tiles from a power supply that provides 3-15 volts, with a max current of 40 amps (the power supply doesn't allow me to limit the current). I want it to heat to ~36 celcius. When I connect a single peltier tile to the power supply at 3 volts, it draws 2.5 amps and heats up too much, more than 80 degrees. How do I reduce the current draw, and how can I scale it to a 64-tile array?

The peltier tiles are part # 04811-5L31-09CK from Custom Thermoelectric.

Comment: The level of detail is totally inadequate on the thermal side.  You need to tell us what you're heating up, how you're connecting the TEC devices to it, how big of a heat sink you have on the cold side, and whether you're running a fan.  If you just took one TEC device in isolation and connected it to 3V, then the temperatures reached mean almost nothing.

Comment: is the whole module getting hot?

Comment: If you're only heating a sample, why not use power resistors as the heating element?

Comment: how hot do they get if you wire 2 in series? 3 in series?

Comment: @TimWescott I'm using the tiles to create a heated(36C) platform for conducting experiments on fruit flies. There will be a glass covering 3mm above the platform to keep the flies in place. The arrangement of the tiles should be as seamless as possible. I don't know if I'll need heat sinks on the cold side, and there is no fan.